# TS does not generate .js files

Tags: typescript

I have this folder structure:

```
- ts
  - index.ts
  - app.ts
  controllers
     - controller.ts
- src
```

And this is my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5" /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */,
    "module": "commonjs" /* Specify what module code is generated. */,
    "rootDir": "./" /* Specify the root folder within your source files. */,
    "moduleResolution": "node" /* Specify how TypeScript looks up a file from a given module specifier. */,
    "allowJs": true /* Allow JavaScript files to be a part of your program. Use the `checkJS` option to get errors from these files. */,
    "outDir": "../src" /* Specify an output folder for all emitted files. */,
    "esModuleInterop": true /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` for type compatibility. */,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */,
    "strict": true /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,
    "noImplicitAny": true /* Enable error reporting for expressions and declarations with an implied `any` type.. */,
    "strictNullChecks": true /* When type checking, take into account `null` and `undefined`. */,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true /* When assigning functions, check to ensure parameters and the return values are subtype-compatible. */,
    "strictBindCallApply": true /* Check that the arguments for `bind`, `call`, and `apply` methods match the original function. */,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true /* Check for class properties that are declared but not set in the constructor. */,
    "noImplicitThis": true /* Enable error reporting when `this` is given the type `any`. */,
    "useUnknownInCatchVariables": true /* Type catch clause variables as 'unknown' instead of 'any'. */,
    "alwaysStrict": true /* Ensure 'use strict' is always emitted. */,
    "noUnusedLocals": true /* Enable error reporting when a local variables aren't read. */,
    "noUnusedParameters": true /* Raise an error when a function parameter isn't read */,
    "exactOptionalPropertyTypes": true /* Interpret optional property types as written, rather than adding 'undefined'. */,
    "noImplicitReturns": true /* Enable error reporting for codepaths that do not explicitly return in a function. */,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true /* Enable error reporting for fallthrough cases in switch statements. */,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true /* Include 'undefined' in index signature results */,
    "noImplicitOverride": true /* Ensure overriding members in derived classes are marked with an override modifier. */,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true /* Enforces using indexed accessors for keys declared using an indexed type */,
    "allowUnusedLabels": true /* Disable error reporting for unused labels. */,
    "allowUnreachableCode": true /* Disable error reporting for unreachable code. */,
    "skipLibCheck": true /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
  }
}
```

When i run `tsc` inside of `ts` folder, then it creates the `src` directory with all the folders, but they are empty as you can see in this image

[image]

So what am i doing wrong, why does typescript only generates an empty directory?

Comment: tsconfig & src are in same location. The outdir is `../src` So it will be one level higher than the tsconfig file.

Comment: @LeelaVenkateshK well the question is why its empty. Even if i do `./src` its still empty

Comment: I have tried exact same in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/klvenky/b590334f3521c6b96102c5a2bcd3bf1a). I am able to see the results one directory level above. @bill.gates

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. It was my VSCode setting under `.vscode/settings.json`

```
{
  "files.exclude": {
    "amplify/backend/function/**/*.js": true
  }
}
```

It actually generates the files, but i cant see it on my VSCode